# A script to mass remove a particular character from the top of wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress, bulk

I imported a bunch of posts from my old blogger site into wordpress, but every post now has a ">" character at the top of each post.  Is there a script I could use to mass remove this character?

Comment: Where exactly does the ">" appear? In the post title? Do you want to remove it from the database or just hide it from view for the visitors? Please post a link to a page where it appears.

Answer (score 1):

Run a query on your MySQL database. **First take a backup.**

```
update wp_posts set post_content = TRIM(LEADING '>' FROM post_content);
```

Note if your database table prefix is different, you will need to change the value for wp_posts above.

This also assumes ">" is the very first character.

Comment: Oh and this is for the actual blog post content, not the title.